# How should I correctly handle a question divided into several posts from the same user?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I found four questions, all posted by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17175059/vmak8352), which deal with the same topic, and with the same title. The [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605443/data-table-visualization-in-jetpack-compose) differs from the others only for the wording *"[Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663774/data-table-visualization-in-jetpack-compose-part-2)"*, *"[Part 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679468/data-table-visualization-in-jetpack-compose-part-3)"* and *"[Part 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690290/data-table-visualization-in-jetpack-compose-part-4)"* at the end of the title.

[image]

If you check the questions you find that **they are not duplicates**, but the general topic is the scrolling of two lists in the same layout (explained simply, for those unfamiliar with Android), and there are ***implicit*** references to the previous questions. For example, the first question says:

> I want both rows to scroll simultaneously in horizontal direction. How can I do it?

And the second one starts with:

> Vertical scrolling synchronization of two LazyColumns works like a charm. *...*

For the purpose of discussion, let's assume that the user decided to do this in order not to post a single big post with four small questions (although in this case it is obvious that he ran into the problems at separate times).

Surely it could all be enclosed in a single question, but at the same time in this way you will have more specific posts and with examples that can be reproduced faster.

Also, it is not possible to remove the reference to the "part" from the title with an edit, unless you change it completely (and I think this is up to the author of the post, right?).

Is a flag appropriate? Which one? Or can I do something more?

Comment: as far as i can see they are 4 different questions, but they all lack in detail or clarity

Comment: All the titles could be better - the title should summarize the problem. It is not uncommon for someone to solve one problem, then a day or two later have another one that results in an additional question. Each question should be a standalone question; a followup can reference the previous question but the new question should be able to stand and be answered on its own.

Comment: I assume the user wanted to achieve 4 goals, however if they's asked all in one question, it would've likely been closed as too broad. Not saying the questions are ok, they should individually be assessed and closed if indeed they don't stand on their own

Comment: Here is a litmus test - if I had the same problem as OP, would you think I can type in anything specific in a search engine to find the question and benefit from the answers? Looking at the titles - I don't think I can. *At the very least*, the titles should be improved.

Comment: Even though the questions being asked aren't my area of expertise, none of them look like "follow up" questions. None of them have answers, or even appear to demonstrate an attempt to solve their problem, which can then be seen to "evolve" in the next question. More like, as has been mentioned, they have 4 questions that although about the same application and methodology in the language they are using, aren't actually related. Could well be you've stumbled into a [[meta-tag:help-vampire]]. If it were me, I'd minimally edit the titles so that they are weren't part of a tetralogy.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If the questions are not duplicates of each other then they are different questions and as such, they need to have different titles. The title is supposed to summarize the problem that is to be solved. **Part 4** is not a valid explanation of a problem. This would be a much better title:

> What is the most quick-acting synchronization of LazyColumn's scrolling?

Every question should be evaluated in isolation. If it's a clear question with enough details to answer then you should edit the title to provide a proper description of the issue. Do not wait for the author to do it as they were clearly unable to properly describe the issue in the first place.

This can also be a sign that the question itself is not sufficiently clear. In such case, just vote to close the question and let the author improve it.

Comment: The person is obviously new so I'd just suggest be judicious here with close votes they will likely be confused by that and not understand it. Someone really sould give them guidance on SO and how it works. This is a good opportunity to gain an enthusiastic SO user, as opposed to turn yet someone else away because of (perceived) pedantic rule enforcement. (I totally get the concern: the titles are not clear enough (etc) , but they are clearly trying to not be too broad)

Comment: @eric close votes are useful in the sense they give a clear indication of what the user needs to do with their question in order to put it in a better shape. Also, the OP did receive guidance, see for example some of the comments on their questions. Maybe we should give them the [how-to-ask] link?

Comment: Yes maybe my wording was bad. There really isn't any other option than close votes so how are people supposed to "be judicious" with them? I was more just trying to urge ppl to be chill with the noob b/c Stack Overflow is hard at first.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is considered good form to post a new question when you have received an answer, changed your original code but got a follow-up question. (As opposed to editing the existing question to ask something else, which is definitely not ok.)

In case a series of follow-up questions is what's happening, there's not necessarily anything wrong going on, assuming each question is indeed different and "stand-alone".

Though there's reason to suspect that the question titles aren't very meaningful. They could perhaps be edited into shape by someone who knows the topic. Any user can do this, not just the OP.

---

So the course of action when encountering a series of questions like this would be:

- If you don't have domain knowledge of the topic, leave it be.
- If you have domain knowledge, see if each of the questions is fine content-wise (not unclear, too broad, duplicate etc). If not, close vote or flag with the appropriate close reason.
- In particular, see if any question is a duplicate of a previous one asked in this same series by checking the poster's question history. Quite often, someone asks the very same question again, but just with more details. This is generally not ok, they should have edited the original question instead.

  But when it happens, close the question with *least details* as a duplicate to the one with *most details*. Which is not necessarily the oldest one. Keep posted answers in mind: in particular, they shouldn't be asking the same question if they have already received answers but not explained why those answers didn't work, that's plain rude. Preferably pick the question with posted answers as the dupe target.

  (In case they asked the same thing several times and received answers more than once, I'd probably pick the oldest post as dupe target though.)
- If the content of the question(s) seems fine and it shouldn't be closed, you could edit them into shape by changing titles, fixing tags, grammar & spelling, formatting and so on.

  NOTE: When you don't have full edit privileges, it's important to only do this when the question shouldn't be closed. Otherwise you are just creating pointless busy-work for other users who have to review your edits, even though the question should just be closed anyway, "lipstick on a pig". Such edits can be done after the OP has made clarifications and the post has been re-opened.
- You can optionally leave a comment pointing out any problems with their question. And optionally you can chose to be more tolerant with new users. And optionally up/down vote as you see fit.

Comment: @Cristik Yes, my intention was to provide a general answer for future readers.